# .NET (MVC) implementations of OAuth WRAP

Tags: .net

Are there any?

I can't find any examples of this anywhere :(

This: http://oauth-wrap-wg.googlegroups.com/web/WRAP-v0.9.7.2.pdf?gda=k-RR5kQAAABFB7PFAFiVedPtjcqT8uuIPJ0_oruXLUh15u1yfw6sJxidFvlYqd_ZjmG9h9kh5-pV6u9SiETdg0Q2ffAyHU-dzc4BZkLnSFWX59nr5BxGqA

is WRAP.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Like [this](http://oauth.net/code/) you mean?

Or this one: [OAuth: Getting Started with OAuth in C#, .NET](http://blog.stevienova.com/2008/04/19/oauth-getting-started-with-oauth-in-c-net/)

Comment: I misunderstood WRAP. Can you explain what you mean by that? I thought as in 'wrapper'.

Comment: http://oauth-wrap-wg.googlegroups.com/web/WRAP-v0.9.7.2.pdf?gda=k-RR5kQAAABFB7PFAFiVedPtjcqT8uuIPJ0_oruXLUh15u1yfw6sJxidFvlYqd_ZjmG9h9kh5-pV6u9SiETdg0Q2ffAyHU-dzc4BZkLnSFWX59nr5BxGqA

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/12238537/OAuth-WRAP
OAuth WRAP has been deprecated in favor of the OAuth 2.0 specification which the IETF community has been working on over the past six months.
Hey dude i also looking for Oauth Wrap samples i find on msdn
Messenger Connect OAuth WRAP Samples
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff750690.aspx